# Understanding simple ANSI C math expression in terms of C#

Tags: c#, math

I've been presented what I think is an ANSI C statement but I don't understand what it is doing or if it is even valid.

x = (y == 4) * 12 + (y == 5) * 24;

Can anyone help me understand what this statement does in terms of C# (which I actually understand).

Thanks

Comment: `x = (y == 4 ? 1 : 0) * 12 + (y == 5 ? 1  :  0) * 24;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, C did not have a boolean type.<sup>*</sup> Comparison operators returned either `0` or `1`, type `int`. Any `int` value (as well as other types) could be interpreted in boolean context, where `0` means false and any other value means true.

C# treats `int` and `bool` as completely separate types. The most direct C# equivalent is

```
x = (y == 4 ? 1 : 0) * 12 + (y == 5 ? 1 : 0) * 24;
```

Which can of course be improved greatly further.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Typically, "ANSI C" is intended to refer to the original version of C, even though later versions of C have been adopted by ANSI too. Those later versions do add a boolean type, but the comparison operators still return `int` values. Similarly, integers in boolean contexts are still allowed as well. They do not change anything relevant to your question.</sub>

Comment: I didn't know this! This is the reason of so many integers treated as booleans...

Comment: Thanks. I will use this in reply to the homework question, though I suspect the question is either a mistake or poorly explained.

Comment: Comparison and boolean operators still yield an `int` result. `_Bool` is just usefull for variables, e.g. `_Bool b = 5;` or `int *p = NULL; _Bool b = p;`.

Comment: @Olaf I know. I mentioned only what the original version of C was like, because the later additions don't change anything relevant to this question. Which is pretty much what you wrote in your comment. :)

Comment: That was actually my point, as your answer implies things have changed to C++ behaviour (I sometimes wish it had) using past tense.

Comment: @Olaf The reason for the past tense is that the question is about an old version of C, not the current one. I hadn't intended for it to imply any change in behaviour (nor of lack thereof). I simply wanted to leave C99/C11 out of it. Added a note.

Comment: I would not bet a dime on OP really meaning C89. There are still many people who just use the term "ANSI-C" in contrast to (pre-standard) K&R-C, but actually mean standard C (i.e. C11, C99 is not standard-C). Point is the behaviour has not changed with C99/C11, as you now have added. Which makes past tense obsolete. I just wanted to have this clarified, which you did somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely wrong in C#. Both expressions, `y==4` and `y==5` are evaluated as a boolean. That being said, how can you define the multiplication between a boolean and an integer? This expression is not correct in C#.

I would say that you could try the following:

```
x = (y == 4 ? 1 : 0) * 12 + (y == 5 ? 1 : 0) * 24;
```

In the above expression we use the ternary operator, whose logic is quite simple it the expression evaluates to true then return the result after the question mark. Otherwise it returns the value after the `:`. So if `y` is equals to 4, then `(y == 4 ? 1 : 0)` evaluates to 1. Otherwise, it returns 0.

The above solution is based on that hvd mentioned below in his comment, that `==` returns either 0 or 1 in C.

Comment: Its plain not really logical! :P

Comment: Well, we don't know the type of y... it *is* possible for this code to compile in C#, using some "unusual" overloaded operators. (I've just proved that...)

Comment: In C, `==` returns `0` or `1` which can be used as a number just as well as a truth value. This answer is totally wrong.

Comment: I did not think it was right but I was thrown by the fact that it was part of the homework for my coding class. I suspect somebody is trying to express something in pseudocode and it makes no sense.

Comment: Heh, I was typing up my own similar answer. Yeah, looks right to me.